# Flutter (emulator) doesn't connect to local Socket.io

Tags: android, node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my local server in [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) using Flutter. It works ok when i connect from my browser, but it doesn't connect using my Android/iOS emulators. My socket.io code is pretty simple

```js
// socket messages
io.on("connection", client => {
    console.log("New device connected!")

    // print in the console when some device disconnects
    client.on("disconnect", data => {
        console.log("disconnected!")
    })
})
```

Flutter code (also pretty simple too):

```dart
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': false,
});

// Dart client
socket.on('connect', (_) {
    print('connect');
});
socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('disconnect'));
socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));
```

It always displays **"disconnect"** every ~30 seconds (in flutter console), also in the node.js it never displays a **"New device connected!"**

---

What i'm using?

[Flutter Socket.io Dependency](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client)

pubspec.xml

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  socket_io_client: ^0.9.11
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's different reasons of why this is not working, but here i describe a couple of them of how you can solve it.

**First check if server is responding**

1. Check if you can access it using your pc web browser, it should something like

[image: node.js console]

2. Check if your device web browser have access

[image]

If both things are working fine, try with one of these solutions:

---

### Solution #1

The url that you've tested in the emulator browser (not in your pc browser) is the same url that you need to use in your flutter app.

**iOS**

```
http://localhost:3000 # port can change, check your node.js config
http://<your_pc_ip:3000>:3000 # you can check it in the preferences or terminal -> ipconfig
```

**Android**

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000
http://localhost:3000 # port can change, check your node.js config
http://<your_pc_ip:3000>:3000 # you can check it in the preferences or terminal -> ipconfig
```

### Solution #2

My node.js project was using socket.io version 3.0.0 (the latest), but it looks like my flutter client doesn't support it, so try to downgrade to version 2.3.0 (don't do it manually, in other words don't modify the file manually)

```sh
npm uninstall socket.io
npm install socket.io@2.3.0
```

and your package.json will be (in your node.js project)

```json
"dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
}
```

**Note**: if you want to keep using socket.io version 3.0 instead of v2.3.0 then you should use the new version of flutter client (currently in beta): [Flutter Client for Socket.io v3.0](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/socket_io_client/versions/2.0.0-beta.2)

### Solution #3

For some reason the **"autoConnect"** not always work, so try to connect it manually.

```dart
IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://localhost:3000', <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': true,
});
    
// Dart client
socket.on('connect', (_) {
    print('connect');
});
socket.on('event', (data) => print(data));
socket.on('disconnect', (_) => print('disconnect'));
socket.on('fromServer', (_) => print(_));

// add this line
socket.connect();
```

### Solution #4

Maybe there's a firewall or something blocking your port (mine 3000), try to run it using another port. You need to change the config in your server and also change the url in the flutter app (also test it using your emulator/simulator browser)

and that's it... it should work.

You should see something like:
**Flutter**

[image: Flutter Code]

**Server**

[image]

Comment: I've been struggling with this for two days. Downgrading my server's socket io version worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!! I've been searching for this since hours. @ben There is a beta of the client now that works with v3 `socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.2`

Comment: Thanks for the update @MindStudio, let me update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much my problem was in the socket.io I have installed the new version but when I downgraded to the version you gave it worked fine

Comment: Thanks you so much. I can not find problem few days. Downgrading worked for me. My server socket.io version is `^3.1.2` and flutter socket client version is `^2.0.0-beta.2`

Comment: Flutter side: socket_io_client: ^2.0.0-beta.2, NodeJS side: "socket.io": "^4.1.3" works for me :) Thank you!

Comment: you solution 3 works for me on flutter. Manuall connection + 10.0.2.2 ip address + npm i socket.io@2.4.1  works . thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Issue using socket_io_client.
Using :`Socket socket = io(SERVER_ADRESS, <String, dynamic> { 'transports':['websocket'], 'autoConnect' : true});` instead of : `Socket socket = io(SERVER_ADRESS);`.